# Bootstrap Modal in cakePHP not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I have tried implementing bootstrap modal with CakePHP in the default.ctp file but its not working...
I have already installed bootstrap and referenced it with

```
   <?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.js')?>
   <?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min.js') ?>
```

in my default.ctp file

My modal code is:

```
 <header>
        <div class="header-title">...</div>
        <div class="header-help">
          <div id="signin">Sign In</div>
          <div id="signup"><button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Create Account</button></div>
          <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h3>Modal Body</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                   </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

is there something i am doing wrong or is there another way to implement modal...by the way i am new to cakePHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Look at the console to make sure there's no errors
2. Look for potential dependency problems (are there any other library that's causing conflict with bootstrap?)
3. Did bootstrap load correctly (Is the path correct?)

Comment: this works : <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> but <?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min')?> does not work

Comment: The first one is an external link. The second one will look for the local js file. Make sure bootstrap.min.js exists inside the app/webroot/js folder

Answer (score 0):

First, remove bootstrap.js and just use the .min version. Then change

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min.js')?>
```

To

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min')?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console, both on startup and when you click the button?